# Stop tree item in CTreeCtrl from expanding - MFC

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am looking for a way to **not** allow a tree node to expand when the user either double-clicks it or clicks on the (+) icon of the tree node.

I tried handing `TVN_ITEMEXPANDING` notification and setting `*pResult` to 1 but the item is still getting expanded. The code in the below handler is getting executed but the tree item still expands. Am I missing something here?

Code sample of what I have tried

```
void CMyTreeCtrl::OnItemexpanding(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{
    *pResult = TRUE;
}
```

Here, `CMyTreeCtrl` is derived from `CTreeCtrl`.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: [TVN_ITEMEXPANDING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tvn-itemexpanding) is sent to a tree-view control's parent. Are you using message reflection? If not, you'll have to handle the notification in the parent.

Comment: @IInspectable I am using message reflection in my Message Map as shown below. The message map of CMyTreeCtrl class.


ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT(TVN_ITEMEXPANDING, OnItemexpanding)

Comment: Try using [ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT_EX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/tn062-message-reflection-for-windows-controls) instead. It allows you to explicitly request the parent not handle the message. I believe you have to return `TRUE` to trigger that behavior.

Comment: @IInspectable I tried using ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT_EX but to no help. The tree node still expands. Any other tip?

Comment: As @IInspectable said, could be a reflection - object handling issue. See MSDN documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tvn-itemexpanding  - Returns TRUE to prevent the list from expanding or collapsing.